# Write unit tests with mocks in java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm a bit new with unittesting and everything about Mocks so I think I could use some help.

I need to write unit tests for this code:

```
@Service
public class TwitterService {

    @Autowired(required=false)
    private Twitter twitter;

    private static final int RESULTSIZE = 5;


    public List<TwitterDTO> getTweets(String tag)
    {
        String searchTag = "#" + tag;
        SearchParameters param = new SearchParameters(searchTag);
        param.count(RESULTSIZE);
        param.resultType(ResultType.RECENT);

        List<TwitterDTO> tweetList= new ArrayList<TwitterDTO>();


        SearchResults results = twitter.searchOperations().search(param);

        for(Tweet tweet: results.getTweets()) {
            TwitterDTO twitterDTO = new TwitterDTO();
            twitterDTO.setTweetId(tweet.getId());
            twitterDTO.setName(tweet.getUser().getName());
            twitterDTO.setUserNameTwitter(tweet.getFromUser());
            twitterDTO.setCreatedDate(tweet.getCreatedAt());
            twitterDTO.setMessage(tweet.getUnmodifiedText());
            twitterDTO.setRetweetCount(tweet.getRetweetCount());
            twitterDTO.setFavoriteCount(tweet.getFavoriteCount());
            twitterDTO.setProfileImageUrl(tweet.getProfileImageUrl());
            twitterDTO.setTwitterUrl("https://twitter.com/" + tweet.getFromUser() + "/status/" + tweet.getId());
            tweetList.add(twitterDTO);
        }

        return tweetList;
    }

    public boolean isAvailable()
    {
        return this.twitter != null;
    }
```

So far I have this as far as my testng knowledge goes:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestTwitterLogic {


    @Mock
    private Twitter twitter;

    @InjectMocks
    private TwitterService service;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testService()
    {
        assertTrue(service.isAvailable());
        service.getTweets("test");
    }

}
```

All advice or help is welcome,
Thanks!

Comment: And what is your problem with this code?

Comment: This unittest does not cover the case of `Twitter` is not injected (required=false) which probably cause `NullPointerException` at `SearchResults results = twitter.searchOperations().search(param);`

Comment: I need to mock the calls to twitter instead of actually making the calls, edited where I am so far, some expleining about mocks or others is also always welcome

Comment: Maybe you want to start with a Mockito tutorial and come back with a more specific problem. I'm guessing that the question in its current form might be too broad to be answered here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock `twitter.searchOperations().search(param)`. Mocking frameworks don't support mocking whole chains of method calls; that's why you need to mock each part of the chain:

```
SearchOperations searchOpMock = mock( SearchOperations.class );
when( twitter.searchOperations() ).thenReturn( searchOpMock );
```

mocks the first part. You can now define one or more search results and mock `searchOpMock.search()`:

```
when( searchOpMock.search( any( SearchParameters.class ) ) ).thenReturn( results );
```

`any( SearchParameters.class )` means "I don't care whether the search uses the correct parameters". You have to use code like that when a class doesn't implement a proper `equals()` method (for example, when it inherits `equals()` from `Object`).